# Haproxy container unable to reach backend server - getting "backend 'servers' has no server available!" error

Tags: haproxy, podman

## [TL;DR]

I have a container environment that works fine with docker (and used to work with podman) but when switching to podman it fails to work correctly. This is strange since I thought that podman was supposed to be a superset of docker.

### Description:

I have a setup where I'm using Haproxy as a load balancer in a containerized environment. The Haproxy container is responsible for routing traffic to a backend server, which is also running in a separate container. This setup has been working flawlessly for over two weeks, but suddenly, without any changes made, the Haproxy container is unable to reach the backend server.

haproxy.cfg:

```
global
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
  daemon
    
defaults
  timeout connect 10s
  timeout client 40s
  timeout tarpit 1m
  timeout server 120s
    
frontend app
  mode http
  bind *:80
  default_backend servers
    
backend servers
  mode http
  balance leastconn
  server app-001 app-001:5000 check
    
listen stats
  bind *:9999
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats uri /stats
  stats hide-version
```

containers are started with the following commands:

```
podman run -d --rm --name app-001 --network my-network -v /path/dst/data:/data app-image
podman run -d --name haproxy-container --network my-network -p 80:80 -p 9999:9999 -v /path/dst/haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy haproxy-image
```

In the `haproxy` folder are two files, the `haproxy.cfg` and a `haproxy.sock` file. Now the only possible missing information that might be useful are the container images. Since the `app-001` image is working perfectly fine on its own, I will only share the image for the haproxy-container, that is:

```
FROM docker.io/haproxytech/haproxy-alpine:latest
    
RUN touch /var/run/haproxy.sock && apk add socat && apk add curl
```

Running the `podman logs haproxy-container` gives the following output:

> [NOTICE] (1): New worker (3) forked
>
> [NOTICE] (1): Loading success.
>
> [WARNING] (3): Server servers/app-001 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 timeout,
> check duration: 2003ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions
> active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
>
> [ALERT] (3): backend 'servers' has no server available!'

Steps taken:

- Verified that the backend server (app-001) is running and accessible independently.
- Checked the network settings of both the Haproxy container and the app-001 container, and they appear to be correctly configured within the same podman network.
- Tried pinging the app-001 server IP address from within the Haproxy container, but it resulted in 100% packet loss.
- Reviewed the haproxy.cfg file for any misconfigurations, but it appears to be correct.
- Uninstalled the Podman container engine entirely and installed it again. This did not resolve the situation.
- I tried the minimal reproducible example on another machine (altough with the same os 22.04) and it still gave the trouble I am describing.
- I tried switching to Docker and this resolves my issues. However, the question remains why it does not work with podman.

I'm seeking help to understand why the Haproxy container is suddenly unable to reach the backend server and how to resolve this issue. I've already tried the steps mentioned above, but none of them have yielded a solution.

### Minimal Reproducible Example:

In my current directory `dst` I have three directories:

- **Containerfiles**

  - AppContainerfile
  - HAProxyContainerfile
- **data**
- **haproxy**

  - haproxy.cfg
  - haproxy.sock
- test_app.py

Now the `HAProxyContainerfile` was given above and the `AppContainerfile` is given by:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk update && apk add python3 && python -m ensurepip --upgrade && pip3 install Flask Flask_RESTful && mkdir data

COPY test_app.py .

CMD ["python","-m","test_app"]
```

Now the code in the `test_app.py` file is given by:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from pathlib import Path

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

data_path = Path.cwd() / 'data'


class Endpoint(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return list(map(lambda f: str(f.name), data_path.iterdir()))

api.add_resource(Endpoint, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

the `data` directory can be filled with some empty files or just be left empty. And the the `haproxy.cfg` file was presented above and the `haproxy.sock` file is empty, but needs to be there to dynamically add servers to haproxy (later in the project). No by executing the following podman commands:

```
podman build -f Containerfiles/AppContainerfile -t app-image .
podman build -f Containerfiles/HaproxyContainerfile -t haproxy-image .
podman network create my-network
podman run -d --rm --name app-001 --network my-network -v /path/dst/data:/data app-image
podman run -d --name haproxy-container --network my-network -p 80:80 -p 9999:9999 -v /path/dst/haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy haproxy-image
```

It used to be that everything was fine and I could make request to port `:80` and it would be served by `app-001` through my haproxy container. Also, by going to `http://localhost:9999/stats` I could see my server being green/checked/running. But now it does not work.

## Important!

If in the above commands you replace each word `podman` with `docker` everything works fine (provided that you have installed docker correctly). Using the podman command, the app container runs just fine, therefore I believe it has something to do with how podman recovers the base image `docker.io/haproxytech/haproxy-alpine:latest` where the problem recides.

Comment: Your haproxy configuration appears to work just fine. I suspect the problem is with your application container. Please update your question to include a [mcve] so that we are able to reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Using your updated example (after correcting the errors in your Dockerfile), I'm still unable to reproduce the problem. I can connect to the published haproxy port, and it successfully forwards to the app container. Both haproxy and the flask app log the connection.

Comment: What errors in the Dockerfile/Containerfile? Well, thanks a lot for trying. I am not surprised that it works on your end, It used to work flawlessly on my end as well.

Comment: @larsks Did you try my minimal reporducible example (MRE) with docker or podman? I have tried the MRE with docker and then I am also unable to reproduce the problem. That is, everything works fine if I use docker.

Comment: I am using podman, as in your example. With respect to errors in your Dockerfile, try building it. Installing the `python3` package does not result in a command named `python` being available.

Comment: I (of course) build the Docker/Container-file and it works as described in my question. It does run the 'app-001' container with no problems. That is, I can post requests to it end it gives back code 200. So on my machine the command ```python``` is available inside the container.

Comment: I may have a cached older version of the `alpine` image available locally. In any case, with podman it all works correctly. I just tried it with Docker as well and I'm seeing the same behavior in both cases.

Comment: @larsks I understand that you already spent quite a lot of time on this issue. But what would you do in my situation? Things I have not tried yet